# Set the 'onClick' to call a client method when dynamically adding control in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, radiobuttonlist

I am dynamically adding a RadioButtonList in the Code Behind. I want it so that the 'OnClick' does not call JavaScript, but instead it calls a method in my code behind.

Is this possible?

In addition, is there a way to set it up so that this say control has runat="server"?

Comment: Show us what you have tried already

Comment: RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList { ID = "rblOther" };
ListItem li = new ListItem("Some description", "Some Value");
li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "RadioButtonListSelectChange()");
rbl.Items.Add(li);
div.Controls.Add(rbl);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Also, there is no need to have runat="server" since your are creating the control in code.

You need to set your RadioButtonList object's OnSelectedIndexChanged event. As @Robert mentioned, if you are creating controls dynamically you need to wrap them in the Page_Init().

```
    protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        RadioButtonList radiobuttonlist = new RadioButtonList();

        radiobuttonlist.SelectedIndexChanged += radiobuttonList_CheckedChanged;

        //Set the AutoPostBack to true proptery to that the user action
        // will immediately post-back to the server

        radiobuttonlist.AutoPostBack = true;
    }

    private void radiobuttonList_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Code you want to execut when a user selects a different item
    }
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.SelectedIndexChanged(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: @dawsoad Awesome! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Button Click Event
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have to use a RadioButtonList though. It does not have a 'click' event.

Comment: You can detect changes using the SelectedIndexChanged in that case.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add the control in the `Page_Init()` portion of the code, not in `Page_Load()` or later.  Set up the event handler `+=` line inside the `Page_Init()` setup.  The control should run server side if you do this.  I'm not sure if `runat="server"` will be explicitly set but the control will behave that way.

Comment: That works for the "runat" issue I am encountering. Any clue about the "onclick"?

Comment: Thanks for figuring this part out for me!

Comment: @dawsoad sorry I was in a hurry when I answered and forgot which events were/weren't available on radiobuttonlist.  Glad that ertdiddy and dbagley could explain it!