# RadioButtonList selection not working properly on AutoPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist, autopostback

I needed to set the AutoPostBack property to true in order for my SelectedIndexChanged event to fire each time a radio button item was selected. Now for some reason if I click the second item or second to last item on the list, that I item never gets selected. The screens flickers; postback, and either the first or last item on the RadioButtonList is selected instead.

Is there a way to handle/prevent this from occurring?

Comment: I would like to add that if you select the second item on the list, the SelectedIndexChanged event does not even fire, the AutoPostBack does occur though. Could this have something to do with it? I currently do not have any code executing in this event either.

Comment: can you post some of you code please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510291/set-the-onclick-to-call-a-client-method-when-dynamically-adding-control-in-cod

Comment: Ok. Removing the 'AutoPostBack' on the RadioButtonList gets rid of the behavior I mentioned; at least when clicking on the items on the RadioButtonList, but now the SelectedIndexChanged does fire unless I click another; e.g. button, on the page that triggers a postback. So that is bad lol. Secondly, by removing the 'AutoPostBack', the same behavior happens when triggering the postback, if the second item on the list is clicked :(

Answer (score 0):

There could be number of reasons why your code acting strange.
You could try following

1) Check if the 
You might be missing the OnSelectedIndexChanged attribute in the definition of Radiobutton list.
Add `OnSelectedIndexChanged="EventMethod"` to `RadioButtonList` control definition.

2) EnableViewState may set to false on top of the page! Set it to true
Add this line `<%@ Page EnableViewState="true" >`

If none of above work kindly post Your source code so that missing part could be recognized.

Comment: Here is a link to another question I posted with the code I am basing this new query on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510291/set-the-onclick-to-call-a-client-method-when-dynamically-adding-control-in-cod

Answer (score 0):

I see where the issue is now. Tricky one to find. It appears that because the first two items on my list have the same exact value, when the postback occurs it uses the selected value to set the item. To remedy the issue, I had to add some variation to the values when adding them to the RadioButtonList's list items, so that they are unique. Issue solved! :) 
I hope if anyone encountering this issue, this posting helps them out.